# How to find the sum(total) of dynamic column of gridview using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, datagridview

[image]

I want the total of column at the Gridview Footer , Possibility that columns can change dynamically so total should be according to those columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Total in Gridview when autogenerate columns is set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477100/calculating-total-in-gridview-when-autogenerate-columns-is-set-to-false)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code if you want to find total dynamic column and if you want to delete last one or two column may be this will help you :

```
for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++row) {
bool isEmpty = false;
for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; ++col) {
    object value = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value;
    if (value  == null || value  == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhitespace(value .ToString()) {
        isEmpty = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (isEmpty) {
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row--);
}}
```